# Isn't it redundant to declare the data type of an event object in a listener function's parameters?

Tags: actionscript-3

When you click on the button something happens.  However it seems redundant to me that in the declaration of myListenerFunction, the event object **e** of class **MouseEvent**, actually has to have its data type **MouseEvent** mentioned.

```
mybutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myListenerFunction);

function myListenerFunction(e:MouseEvent):void
{
     // function body
}
```

Couldn't I get away with this (the .swf works just the same so far as I know...)?

```
 function myListenerFunction(e):void
```

Since the data type of **e** should always match the class of the event MouseEvent.CLICK (which is **MouseEvent**)?

### EDIT:

So let's say we go from a mouse event to a keyboard event.  By not declaring the data type of e, we can not be prone to errors in not changing the data type of e.  e by default is going to be of type KeyboardEvent

```
mybutton.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myListenerFunction);

function myListenerFunction(e):void
{
     // function body
}
```

Comment: If you assigned `myListenerFunction` to some other event, how will it know what kind of event object `e` is if you don't declare it in the function?

Comment: It would know because the kind of event object e is, is the same as the class of the first parameter of the addEventListener function.

Comment: @BoltClock See the edit to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the event type to the base class `Event` if you like. But you will not have access to any of the `MouseEvent` / `KeyboardEvent`-specific members when you do it like that.

Using it without a type will make it `Object`, which is dynamic, meaning you can try to access any member by name (even if it does not exist) - this is slower (a lot) and fairly error prone. You will not get compile time checking for example.